# Finding Process times outside of the Avg

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have data that shows a request creation and completion Date/Time. I am looking to find outliers that take longer than average to complete. So I have 2 questions.

1. I am currently subtracting the Completion Date and the Creation date, then looking for the average. My plan is to just subtract the average from the actual and see what the biggest outliers are. I can't seem to figure out how to show the Total Average across all the rows; it keeps breaking it out. How can I do this?
2. Is there a better way all together? Maybe I am thinking about this wrong.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFMXY.png)

Comment: You need to change context when calculating the average. There are lots of materials to read to understand context, which is essential for writing good DAX queries. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/row-context-and-filter-context-in-dax/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not showing your data or formula used to calculate the average, I'm going to speculate a bit.

I'm guessing your formula for calculating the average is `2. Avg = AVERAGE(Table[1. Time Lapse])`.

The reason it is not showing values you would like in each row is Query context. You can think of it as filters that are applied to your measure, based on where it is evaluated. So when the `2. Avg` formula above is calculated for each row in your table, a query context / filter is applied that tells DAX to retrieve values relating to that person and calculate average based on that.

The grand total is working, as there is no query context resulting from individual rows of the visual. What you need is to change query context when you are calculating values for individual rows in the visual and tell DAX to remove this implicit filter from the calculation.

To do that, you use `CALCULATE` function, the principal purpose of which is to change query context. There are many functions that allow you to alter context. One of them (the most coarse) is `ALL`. Since I don't know much about your data, I'm going to assume that `2. Avg = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Table[1. Time Lapse]), ALL(Table))` is going to do the job and not ruin other applications of the measure.

Just for reference, I recommend to read through these materials to get a better grasp at context in DAX.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/dax-power-bi-modify-filter/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dax-overview#context